# How to make text nodes with new lines in it without using "style=white-space: pre"?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, textnode

I'm trying to get a textnode with new lines in it (my text contains `\n` and `x0a`). I found the way to do this, using `white-space: pre`, and it works, but the problem is that the content doesn't fit to the parent div, I got the new lines in the text, but when the line is long, it goes beyond the window.

This is the code:

```
var textdata = document.createTextNode(text_with_multiples_lines);
PanelBody.style = "white-space: pre;"
PanelBody.appendChild(textdata);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Somebody know how to make new lines inside a textnode without exceeding the window size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `white-space` to `pre-wrap` instead.

This also enables text lines to break as needed to fill the element box :)

More on that: [MDN - white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)